# I want to insert a variable inside a string in NSURL (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, nsurl

My app page has a form where I want the user to input his name and phonenumber.

I want this data to be fetched into the following URL.

The variables are username, phoneno.

`var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https:xyz.com/newRequest?fullname=\(username)&phone=\(phoneno)")!`

Is this the correct syntax for writing the URL with the username and phonenumber parameters as variables.

---

This is what i am trying to implement, but i keep getting error 405 during simulation -

```
var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&phoneno=\(phoneno)"

NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://example.com/newRequest?fullname=(username)&phone=(phoneno)")!

var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = postData
request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Comment: You forgot the backslashes in your source code sample.

Comment: Im just not sure how to use the variable component in the url string...

Answer (score 2):

You should use [NSURLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html) with [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/) instead. Then the system can properly escape the values for you. Like this:

```
let username = "foo"
let phoneno = "bar"

let comps = NSURLComponents(string: "https://example.com/newRequest")
comps?.queryItems = [
    NSURLQueryItem(name: "fullname", value: username),
    NSURLQueryItem(name: "phone", value: phoneno)
]

comps?.URL // returns https://example.com/newRequest?fullname=foo&phone=bar
```

Comment: Thanks ! Could you maybe help me with where to make the changes. I just started using Swift and JSON like 2 days and i'm still not sure about what I'm doing :D

Comment: Thanks. 
So now i dont need to use NSLog , NSData or any of the the request statements that follow ?

Comment: let name = "abc"
        let phone = "123456"
        
        let url = NSURLComponents(string: "https://example.com/newRequest")
        url?.queryItems = [
            NSURLQueryItem(name: "fullname", value: name),
            NSURLQueryItem(name: "phone", value: phone)
        ]
        url?.URL

this is sufficient to replace the above code segment originally posted ?

And instead of the strings in - 
let name = "abc"
let phone = "123456"

I can use variables which already store strings from the app ?
let name = username
let phone = phoneno